# how to subtract days from current date and return date object in pandas

Tags: pandas

I want to subtract 30 days from current date and get date in following format.

```
  final_date = 2019-12-24
```

I am doing following thing in pandas, but getting timestamp object in return

```
  final_date = pd.to_datetime(pd.datetime.now().date() - timedelta(30))
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: do you need string or date object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is more solution for subtract today by [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html) with timedeltas or offsets:

```
final_date =  pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d') - pd.Timedelta(30, unit='d')
final_date =  pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d') - pd.DateOffset(days=30)
final_date =  pd.to_datetime('now').floor('d') - pd.offsets.Day(30)
```

---

```
print (final_date)
2019-12-24 00:00:00
```

And last convert output to python object dates:

```
print (final_date.date())
2019-12-24
```

Or to strings:

```
print (final_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
2019-12-24
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
final_date = (pd.datetime.now().date() - pd.Timedelta(days = 30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
#'2019-12-24'
```

Comment: nice approach indeed